# Grails; how to refer to a domain property in native sql query

Tags: sql, grails, mapping

I have a domain class UserProfile which has one to one relationship with another domain class User.The Structure of the domain is provided.

```
сlass UserProfile {
String fio
String position
String phone
String email

static belongsTo = [user: User]

static constraints = {
          // some constraints
}
static mapping = {
   //some mapping; user property is not mapped
}
```

I need to write a native sql query in Grails for UserProfile domain and I don't know how to refer to user property(static belongsTo = [user: User]). I have tried USER_ID but it is not working.
I can't name the column directly using mapping section; I just need to find out how user column in UserProfile domain is named in database and how it can be called in native sql query.

Comment: if you just need to see schema details, then run `grails schema-export`, it will generate the schema to target/ddl.sql. http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Command%20Line/schema-export.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Simple if i got your question ,Grails gorm convention for storing fileds in data base is:

Like

```
    user_profile  for UserProfile -Domain
```

and all fileds are speparedted by underscores and most of the time gorm adds _id after a foreign key reference /or a GORM relationship like above One to One and one to Many

```
   [belongsTo=[user]] .
```

Inside SQL Table

```
    mysql describe user_profile ;

    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    User_Profile
    ----------------------------------------------------------------
    id
    version 
    foo           varchar(50)   
    postion
    email
    user_instance_id  int 
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

NATIVE SQL QUERY WILL BE :

```
   'select up.user_instance_id from user_profile as up '
```

the Get all the userInstance objects by querying the user table

```
   'select * from user where user.id = 'the id you get it from the above query'
```

I hope you have some idea on this please ,if i didnt get it let me know.

Answer (score -1):

I believe if you define user inside UserProfile, then you can access it and will automatically be mapped?  It works in my previous projects, I hope it will work with this.

```
сlass UserProfile {
String fio
String position
String phone
String email

static belongsTo = [user: User]

User userInstance;

static constraints = {
          // some constraints
}
```

Then you can use it

```
UserProfile.executeQuery("select up.userInstance from UserProfile up")
```

Comment: That's not native SQL. That's HQL.

Comment: The example is HQL, but in SQL you can still reference the property yes?